# Why is the loop not stopping?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEWGEAR 15.0
#define USEDGEAR 5.0

int main() {
    int type;
    int num_items;
    float total;

    printf("Welcome to the market\n");
    printf("What would you like to do\n");
    printf("\t1-Buy New Gear\n");
    printf("\t2-Buy used gear\n");
    printf("\t3-Quit\n");

    scanf("%d", &type);

    while (type != 3) {
        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            printf("How many new items would you like?\n");
            scanf("%d", &num_items);
            total = num_items * 15.0;
            break;
```

This is where the code keeps on asking how many new items would you like?

```
        case 2:
            printf("How many old items would you like?\n");
            scanf("%d", &num_items);
            total = num_items * USEDGEAR;
            break;
```

This is where the code keeps on asking how many old items would you like?
            case 3:
                break;

```
        default:
            printf("Not a valid option\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Your total cost is %f\n",total);

    return 0;
}
```

Both my choices are looping

Comment: Where do you increment `type` so that it will ever have the value `3`? This would be a great time to learn to use a debugger to step through code, so you can figure out problems like this yourself.

Comment: @SamBh: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote those that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You never update the `type` variable to 3, so the while loop never terminates. Although you do have a `break` statement, it is affecting the `switch` and not the `while` loop that surrounds it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? As in are you talking about a case 3?

Comment: Sure– you enter the while loop when `type != 3`, and then every time you finish the flow of your switch statement, the statement `type != 3` is still true, so the while loop executes all of the code inside it again. It keeps doing this until the statement `type != 3` is false. Because you never update the `type` variable to anything, the while loop never terminates.

Comment: Each `case` in a `switch` statement needs a `break`. Therefore, those `break` in each case breaks the `switch` statement NOT your `while` loop. As @Tillson mentioned, if you want to break out of your loop too, `type` should be changed somewhere in your cases.

Comment: Got in working. Thank you so much. I added a break at the end of the while loop and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'll also point out that this may be a case where you don't need a while loop in the first place–– just checking `if (type != 3)` would suffice since your code will always break out of the while loop after its first iteration.

Comment: @SamBh I would recommend using chqrlie's answer if you would want to make users go over the options again to make a new transaction after it finished doing a transaction. That would make more sense for a program emulating a marketplace. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop logic is flawed:

- you should move the prompt code inside the loop.
- you should update `total` for each answer.
- you should test if `scanf()` is successful at converting user input.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEWGEAR  15.0
#define USEDGEAR  5.0

int main() {
    int type;
    int num_items;
    double total = 0;

    printf("Welcome to the market\n");
    for (;;) {
        printf("What would you like to do\n");
        printf("\t1-Buy New Gear\n");
        printf("\t2-Buy used gear\n");
        printf("\t3-Quit\n");

        if (scanf("%d", &type) != 1 || type == 3)
            break;

        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            printf("How many new items would you like?\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &num_items) == 1)
                total += num_items * 15.0;
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("How many old items would you like?\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &num_items) == 1)
                total += num_items * USEDGEAR;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Not a valid option\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Your total cost is %f\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `&&` not `||`. Otherwise, every time that 1 is not entered, it will already break out of the loop since your if condition will be valid to break the loop.

Comment: @Whooper: no,  `||` is correct. `scanf()` returns `1` if and only if the conversion is successful. The loop should end if the conversion is unsuccessful **or** if the type entered is `3`.

Comment: Ahh I get it now! Didn't know scanf can be used this way as a condition. I thought it works the same way as assigning the value read from scanf to `type` first before checking if you should break the loop. Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: @Whooper: `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions. It is important to check that `scanf()` was indeed successful to handle unexpected input correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will handle what you want to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEWGEAR 15.0
#define USEDGEAR 5.0

int main() {
    int type = 0;
    int num_items;
    float total;

    printf("Welcome to the market\n");
    printf("What would you like to do\n");
    printf("\t1-Buy New Gear\n");
    printf("\t2-Buy used gear\n");
    printf("\t3-Quit\n");

    while (type != 3) {
      printf("Enter an option: ");
      scanf("%d", &type);

      if(type == 3)
        break;

      switch (type) {
        case 1:
            printf("How many new items would you like?\n");
            scanf("%d", &num_items);
            total = num_items * 15.0;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("How many old items would you like?\n");
            scanf("%d", &num_items);
            total = num_items * USEDGEAR;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Not a valid option\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Your total cost is %f\n",total);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, after your user finished doing cases 1-2 or default, your program would prompt your user for an option again if he wants to quit or perform another case 1 or 2 operation.

Comment: Take note however that this only handles your loop problem. As chqrlie mentioned in his answer, there are also some logical problems with your code but I think you can figure it out or ask another question about any issues you would encounter.

Comment: @chqrlie ah yeah right since it will still enter the switch-case scenario. Thanks for pointing that out!